# Sybase Python SQL Anywhere 17 SQL Central

Tags: python, sql, sybase, sqlanywhere, central

I don't know which module for python can I use to connect to DB. And use SQL commands INSERT INTO , SELECT to manipulation DB TABLE. Pls help me to find module and example. I have UserId , Password , Host , Port , Server Name , Database Name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check the SAP programming guide for SQL Anywhere which has a section on connecting with Python: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.1/PDF/dbprogramming_en11.pdf